# bootstrap navigation bar items change color when loosing focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following problem with my bootstrap menu bar:
When I click on "Sign in" and then I click on the "En" link the Sign in link becomes black.

I have set the background color to  #ee4035 
I also tried the hover/focus properties.

Any ideas on what I have missed?

Here is a copy of my html:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebj2zt72/

thanks

```
<style>
    .navbar {
    min-height: 80px;
    background: #ee4035;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: blue;
  }

  .navbar a {
    color: white!important;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: white;
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
    margin-top: 23px;
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
  }

  .navbar-btn {
    /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
    background: #f37736;
    border-width: 0px;
  }

  .navbar-text {
    margin-top: 28px;
    color: white;
  }

  .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
  }

  .dropdown-menu {
    background: #ee4035;
  }

  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #d6392f;
  }

  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:focus {
    background-color: #d6392f;
  }
</style>



<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="inline">
          <p class="navbar-text" style="color:white"><strong>goodmorning? </strong></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn"> Click me</button>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="user-navbar" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="lang-selector" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> En <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ellinika</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to update your jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your problem is that you don't want to let the colour of link change or in other words you don't want to see any styling on your link when hovered and/or clicked then you can do so by manually modifying the respective classes whichever you are using or better if you may provide an inline styling(always try to avoid doing it as it over right all the styling you have provided in .css files or under style tag) of your choice as to how you want it to appear in different circumstances.
And brother if you may allow me to help more efficiently then please edit your jsfiddle file, as it is empty and there is not much clear from your problem statement.

About blackening of link, it happens in using bootstrap classes directly sometimes as a glitch because bootstrap classes set the background color in the bootstrap css . So when you toggle the already set background color is displayed . You will have to set it to your liking.

for example, if the default color on the dropdown toggle classes are set to background-color: #111111; and/or #e5e5e5 hypothetically ,thats why you get the dark color on hover.

Comment: I solved it at the end. it was an issue with my custom css. Thanks for your answer.Very helpful